# Full Text Search - only searching certain fields instead of on ALL

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the following data in my mongo database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582b89866b6347a422ab525d"),
    "phnum" : "+11111230023",
    "fax" : "",
    "description" "11111230023"
}
```

and

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582b89866b6347a422ab525d"),
    "phnum" : "+12221230023",
    "fax" : "",
    "description" ""
}
```

I created an index by doing the following:

```
> use widgets
switched to db widgets
> db.ph.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } ,{ default_language: "english" }, {name:"widgettextindex"})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

And then confirmed it's there like so:

```
> db.ph.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "widgets.ph"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "$**_text",
        "ns" : "widgets.ph",
        "default_language" : "english",
        "weights" : {
            "$**" : 1
        },
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
>
```

**Problem**

When I try to run a query for "0023", I'm only getting back one of the two documents.

```
> db.ph.find({'$text':{'$search':'0023'}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("582b897b6b6347a422ab49c0"), "phnum" : "+11111230023", "fax" : "", "description" : "11111230023" }
```

**Questions**

1. Any ideas on what I'm missing / why I'm not getting back both records?
2. Once a text index has been created, do i need to do anything to "maintain" it... or does the system reindex on its own?

Thanks.

ps. I have two mongo servers... one is 3.0.4 and the other is 3.2.10.  I have the same problem on both... which makes me think it's a problem with the way I'm creating the index.

**EDIT 1**

Upon closer examination, it appears that the system is NOT looking in the phnum field for matches.
I previously didn't notice that the record that is consistently being returned has a copy of the phnum in the description. 
As a test, i added the text "0023" to the description field in the doc that wasn't being returned by the search.  Then I retried the search and now both records are being returned.

How do I get the indexing to work on all the fields? 
I thought that the "$**"  syntax would index all fields.

Oh and this issue happens via the mongo command line too.  Not just via PHP mongoclient.  I'll update the title of my post.

**EDIT 2**

I also tried to recreate my index by explicitly listing the fields I want to search:

```
> db.did.createIndex( {"phnum": "text","description":"text"} ,{ default_language: "english" }, {"name":"didtextindex"})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But that still didn't fix the issue.  I can't search for values inside the phnum field.